# Publish Azure App With Database Connection String Using Active Directory Integrated Not Working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, azure-appservice

I have previously deployed an MVC application to Azure.

Under Publish -> Settings -> Databases, I include connection strings.

I have been using the following: `Data Source=tcp:servername.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=dbname;User ID=username;Password=password;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False`

The problem with specifying a user is that stored procedures run as the user specified.

This results in CreatedBy/ModifiedBy values set to this same user, instead of the user that created/modified the record.

I previously tried the following: `Data Source=tcp:servername.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=dbname;Persist Security Info=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Authentication="Active Directory Integrated"`

However, I receive the error "The format of the specified domain name is invalid." after the application is deployed. Even though I test the connection with Active Directory Integrated in the Destination Connection String window, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

- As given in this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sql/azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver16#using-active-directory-integrated-authentication), if you’re using the AD Integrated type of Authentication in the Azure, then either you should have domain-joined device for accessing the Web Application linked with SQL Database or make the device as federations with ADFS.
- So, if you are accessing the Azure Applications from other machines, use the AD-password type authentication mode and its connection string format is given in the same MS Document and this [Doc2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-configure?view=azuresql&tabs=azure-powershell#active-directory-integrated-authentication) for more relevant information on configuring the AD Integrated / Password Type of Authentication mode on Azure Data sources and applications.

AD Password Type Authentication Format:

```sql
Server=demo.database.windows.net; Authentication=Active Directory Password; Encrypt=True; Database=sample_db; User Id=your_username@domain.com; Password=<Your__Password>
```

Comment: Specifying a user Id means that stored procedures run as the specified user. And therefore, attributes that keep track of who created and modified records will be that same user every time. Instead of not specifying a user Id in the connection string and having the stored procedure run as the user that created and modified the record.